# PowerShell function that takes in sweeper arguments

Tags: powershell, shell, scripting

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
function myfunction(...arguments) {
   iex (&some_command ...arguments)
)
}
```

That is some very rough pseudo code, I'm basically making an alias system. You make an alias, and it's spews out some code. Ie, you give it the command_name, and then it is now a function that you can call, and provide as many arguments as you want.

Example:

```
function ss(...args) {
    iex(&starship ...args)
}
```

Then, I can do `ss whatever arguments i want` and that is equivalent to `starship whateverarguments i want`.

Kinda lost!
Any help is much appreciated. Thanks :D

Comment: PowerShell [already has aliases built in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-alias?view=powershell-7.1); why are you trying to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: They don't do it well, you can alias it, but trailing arguments don't get passed through to the command running. This is why I'm trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: This might be an X/Y problem. Have you tried asking how to do something you're not able to, using the existing alias function? Or did you jump straight to your own possible solution and are now having problems implementing that?

Comment: Huh? If you set an alias for a command, it takes exactly the same arguments that the original command does.

Comment: @salvage_dev An alias will accept whatever parameter arguments the target command accepts - can you show us an example where this doesn't appear to work?

Comment: Turns out this was a bug with Posh 5. Just upgraded. Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare an array parameter and apply the `ValueFromRemainingArguments` parameter flag, then [splat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) the array when executing the inner command:

```
function myFunction {
  param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments = $true)]
    [string[]]$Arguments
  )

  & Write-Host @Arguments
}
```

```
PS ~> myFunction whatever arguments i want
whatever arguments i want
```

---

As multiple users have commented, you might want to take advantage of PowerShell's aliasing feature:

```
New-Alias myFunction Write-Host
```

PowerShell will automatically copy the parameter bindings of the target command to the alias, so if the target command accepts trailing arguments, so will the alias. See [the `about_Aliases` help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_aliases) for more information about aliases